# Use available width with css

Tags: html, css

I've a special case. I want a div use the available width.

This is my code:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
}
.child-left {
  width: 66%;
  float: left;
}
.child-right {
  width: 33%;
  min-width: 400px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-left">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
  <div class="child-right">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

The `child-right` element should be minimum 400px width. If i resize the screen the element breaks down. Is there a way, that the `child-left` element use the  available horizontal space? Maybe CSS-Flexbox?

Comment: Can you make the `min-width` value as `%` instead of `px` and try?

Comment: Use media query, for smaller resolution. So that in a particular resolution you can change the with of the respective element.

Comment: That's not an option. The `child-right` must be 400px min-width!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do it with flex yes.

```
.parent{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.child-right{
  flex-basis: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you want to use the available free-space for `child-left` and not allow the `child-right` to wrap to a new line, using a `flexbox` is ideal here:

1. Remove the floats and add `display: flex` to the `parent`.
2. Add `flex: 1` to `child-left` for it to adjust the free-space automatically.
3. Set `min-width` of `child-right` using `flex: 0 1 400px` which means the element will only shrink with a `flex-basis` of 400px.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.child-left {
  flex: 1;
}
.child-right {
  flex: 1 0 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-left">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
  <div class="child-right">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know your feedback on this.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick for cross browser compability, without Flexbox:

```
.child-left {
    width: auto;
    overflow: none;
}
.child-right {
    width: 33%;
    min-width: 400px;
    float: right;
}
```

Please note that you have to place your right child first in HTML. The `float: right;` in `.child-right` makes the div float only with the following element(s). If you place it after `.child-left`, it won't float next to it.

```
<div class="parent">
      <div class="child-right">
        Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="child-left">
        Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
</div>
```

See this in action: https://jsfiddle.net/4s3oecrp/

Also, you should remove your css style for the .parent class. 100% width is useless on elements that have `display: block;` set (default on p, div, section, article, ...), they stretch to their full width automatically.

Answer (score 0):

you can user flex.
just add flex to the parent div

```
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
}
.child-left {
  width: 66%;
  float: left;
}
.child-right {
  width: 33%;
  min-width: 400px;
  float: right;
}

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-left">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
  <div class="child-right">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

for Better learning for
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp